# How to pass value from view to modal?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have this link where i open modal:

```
<li><a href="#deleteProperty{{$property->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
```

And i have modal in seperate page modals.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade modal_form" id="deleteProperty{{$property->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel5" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel5">Are you sure you want to delete this property?</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.property.delete',[$user->id,$property->id])}}">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="left-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-btn">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

How can i pass this parameter ($property->id) to modal so when user click on specific property, to delete that property?

Comment: You are already passing the value to the *bootstrap modal*. It's just a matter of using jQuery(?) to access the `id` attribute of the `.modal` div.

Comment: when i pass this value i get an error undefined variable property

Comment: Are you passing the property to the view?

Comment: yes...i can access property in view

Comment: How are you including the `modals.blade.php` page?

Comment: I have layout where i use  @include('standardUser.includes.modals') and @yield('content') for that view

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variables you want to use in the included views.

Example:

```
@include('standardUser.includes.modals', [ "property" => $property ])
```

Comment: i cant do that because in layout i dont have property

Comment: You need to rethink your strategy then. You need to include the view after you've resolved all properties or you should use `View::share('property','$property)` but that's just bad practice for your case.